# return a long list of constant in Java

Tags: java

I have a class in which 100+ consts are defined

```
public class Codes {

    static final public ErrorCode ISSUE_1 = new ErrorCode(XXX);  
    static final public ErrorCode ISSUE_2 = new ErrorCode(XXX);
    
    // 100+ error codes
}
```

Now I need to define a `Codes.getAll()` to return all the ErrorCode defined in the class.

Is there any elegant way to implement it?

Comment: Convert `ErrorCode` to an `enum`?

Comment: ErrorCode class has multiple fields so if enum in Java can have a constructor with multiple args converting it to enum could be a solution.

Comment: That's not the way that `enum` works.  But yes, the constructor for the enum *values* can have multiple arguments.  Read the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Instead of new ErrorCode you could create a Supplier/Factory class that both creates an error code and then adds the newly created code to a statically available Collection that you can access later. Not sure this qualifies as "elegant" but maybe more transparent and flexible than other options..

Answer (score 0):

using reflection could be a solution;

```
List<ErrorCode> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Field field : Codes.class.getFields()) {
    if (field.getType() == ErrorCode.class) {
        list.add((ErrorCode) field.get(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: *Caveat:* Field list will be unordered.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted an **elegant** solution ...